# MacBook Air Screen Probem

Tags: macbook-pro, display, hardware

My MacBook screen looks like this!!! The laptop hasn't been dropped or anything. I closed it down fine and then when I started it up it looks like this. The laptop works as normal.

[image]

I've tried pressing Command (⌘)-Option-P-R and nothing

Answer (score 3):

That clearly looks like the LCD screen is physically damaged, to me. The vertical stripes below that only serve to reinforce that opinion.

[image]

Comment: Also, the colored banding at the top of screen is clear indication of a broken/cracked LCD.

Comment: The sharp-edged curve in the black bit is conclusive, imo - the rest is merely confirmation. That's a smashed screen, no doubt.

Comment: Okay, thanks for the confirmation. Maybe the cat stepped on it? Who knows